# How to compile a multi-module Python program to a single module?

Tags: python

My Python (3.7) program is split into a number of files just for sake of convenience of development (e.g. Pycharm becomes slow when a module is too big) but I would like to distribute it to end-users as a single py file they can just put anywhere, click and run. This is fairly easy to do manually but that takes some time to copy-paste everything so it would be handy to automate this. Is there a tool for this already or should I write it myself? If I should then should I do it the dumb way by concatenating files and removing imports or are there some functions to do it a right way parsing modules and analyzing imports so the script could actually understand the program structure?

Comment: Have you tried setuptools? You can create windows installer, linux deb etc. Check out this sample on their documentation. https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

Comment: Thanks. I have used setuptools previously and can say it's fairly nice but in this case I'd prefer the zero-install script-style way.

Comment: what about using one of the tools to turn it into a binary? that way all your dependacies are inside a single binary

Comment: I specifically intend the users to hack on the source code "on the fly" between the program runs.